# How to make a variable I made for a counter used to display an image using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, image

I'm trying to display a different image every time someone loads the page, I have no experience working with PHP, but I really need this done, here's the code, the images are on my server on a directory name "imagenes".

```
<?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";

// Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
$f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
fwrite($f,"0");
fclose($f);
}

// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);

// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one

 $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
 $counterVal++;
 $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
 fwrite($f, $counterVal);
 fclose($f); 
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/imagenes);

 echo "You are visitor number $counterVal to this site";
$arr1=array('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg','6.jpg','7.jpg','8.jpg','9.jpg','10.jpg','11.jpg','12.jpg','13.jpg','14.jpg','15.jpg','16.jpg','17.jpg','18.jpg','19.jpg','20.jpg','21.jpg','22.jpg','23.jpg','24.jpg','24.jpg','25.jpg','26.jpg','27.jpg','28.jpg','29.jpg','30.jpg');
```

Comment: Does it have to be a unique image every time? Why not select a random picture out of the array, e.g. using `$arr1[$array_rand($arr1)]`?

Comment: yes, It have to be a specific image, for explample visitor or load page one will see image 1, etc, thank you so much for reply

Comment: why not simply link to the image <?php echo "<img src='/imagenes/$counterVal.jpg'>" ?>

Comment: is exactly what i want but i dindt know how to do it, i copy your answer to my code and it said i have a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to do this, if you truly want a random image being displayed, then you can do;

$num = rand(1, 30) //number between 1-30

//display image

```
<img src="path-to-image/<?php echo $num."jpg"; ?>">
```

However if it had to be a unique image, then you would need to add a field into the .txt file to log what images have already been shown;

OR you could do the exact same at the top, but have $counterVal instead of $num

```
<img src="cinreyesbarrandey.com/Imagenes/<?php echo $counterVal; ?>.jpg">
```

Comment: and how can I do that? Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Did you want the unique image example? How many images do you have?

Comment: Okay, use the 2nd example in my answer

Comment: ok I apologize for my ignorance but should it look like this?, to be honest i never used php before
    <img src="http://www.cinreyesbarrandey.com/imagenes/ <?php echo $counterVal."jpg"; ?>">

Comment: I put it and it gave error, :/ where should i put it? at bottom?

Comment: Make sure you put it outside the ?> tag